# Simplify command lines in script

Tags: shell-script

I have this script and would like to simplify it. Any help would be appreciated:

```
#!/bin/ash
chmod 775 /path/to/directory
chown -R http:http /path/to/directory
cd /path/to/directory
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; ; find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

chmod 775 /path/to/directory1
chown -R http:http /path/to/directory1
cd /path/to/directory1
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; ; find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

chmod 775 /path/to/directory2
chown -R http:http /path/to/directory2
cd /path/to/directory2
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; ; find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ash
for i in \
         '/path/to/directory'  \
         '/path/to/directory1' \
         '/path/to/directory2' \
;do
    chmod 775 "$i"
    chown -R http:http "$i"
    cd "$i" && \
    find . \
       -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; \
                  -o \
       -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
    done
```

## Explanation

Since you are doing the same set of operations on dir1/2/3 then it makes sense to move them under a loop.

The two find commands can also be moved inside one taking help of Boolean logic rules.

Comment: That seems to have worked just fine. Thank you. :)

Comment: Just a note of caution: The for loop had fullpaths is the reason the cd-s worked. IOW, if you give relative paths to for loop then the above would not work. In that case you can move the cd+find duo into a subshell. Alternatively, you could save the PWD from where the script ran and then afte rthe find cd back to it. All this due to the fact that the bourne shell are sorely lacking the infamous Cshell's pushd/popd constructs.

Comment: @RakeshSharma The common way to temporarily change directory is to do it in a sub-shell:  `(cd dir && somecommand )`

Comment: @Kusalananda That's correct & I mentioned about it as well: `cd+find duo into a subshell` in my comment .

Comment: @RakeshSharma You did indeed.

Comment: Thanks guys. All this is too technical for me. I'll simply stick to the full path. :)